# Java - Insert an element after every n elements in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays

My aim is to create an array of 22 elements in which there must be 11 elements "G" and 11 elements "B". Every 5th element in the array is "B".

That is, the 5th element in the array is B, the 10th is B, the 15th is B and 20th is B. The array should wrap after the last element and skip the existing B elements, hence the next B is the 3rd element, followed by the 9th element and so on.

So far, this is my code and present output:

```
private static ArrayList<String> circle;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    circle = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i=0; i< 22; i++){
        circle.add("G");
    }

    for(int i=0; i<circle.size(); i++){
        if((i+1) % 5 == 0){
            circle.set(i, "B");             
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<circle.size(); i++){
        System.out.printf("%3d", (i+1));
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
    for(int i=0; i<circle.size(); i++){
        System.out.printf("%3s", circle.get(i));
    }

}
/* Output */
/*  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
    G  G  G  G  B  G  G  G  G  B  G  G  G  G  B  G  G  G  G  B  G  G */
```

The desired output is

```
/* Desired Output */
/*  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
    B  G  B  G  B  B  G  B  G  B  B  G  B  G  B  G  G  B  G  B  G  G */
```

How do I go about it?
Thanks!

Comment: I find the question to be unclear, especially the part that begins "After that, the next 5th element is (21,22,1,2,3)...". Also, it's not a good idea to name your variable starting with a capital letter (unless it's a constant in which case it should be all caps) please see [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Comment: @D.B. I have made an edit to the post which should help clarify it. I agree about the naming convention - at first I thought `Circle = ArrayList<>` was a typo! To everyone else - don't mass-downvote it until the question has been edited!

Comment: Hi! Sorry about the confusion and thanks for the edit CJxD.
@J.Baoby When the arraylist has 11 "B"s.

Comment: I just spent 5 minutes trying to work out why my method wasn't working, but realised your made a miscalculation. It should go 3 -> 8 -> 13 rather than 3 -> 9 -> 14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    int max = 22;
    int count = 0; // count number of B's
    String x[] = new String[22];
    int i = 4; // starting index
    while (count < 11) {
        x[i] = "B";
        count++;
        int c = 0;
        // we will take five steps to find new index
        while (c < 5) {
            i++;
            i%=22;
            if(x[i] == "B") ; // dont count it as step if its already B
            else c++;
        }

    }
    // fill with G
    for (i = 0; i < 22; i++) {
        if (x[i] != "B")
            x[i] = "G";
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
```

output is

```
[B, G, B, G, B, G, B, G, B, B, G, G, G, B, B, B, G, G, G, B, G, B]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the loop bit that matters - it replaces the for loop that sets the Bs in your original code.

```
    int numBs = 0;
    int idx = 4;
    while (numBs < 11) {
        Circle.set(idx % 22, "B");
        numBs++;
        idx += 5;
    }
```

It's starting from index 4 (since the first element is 0, the 5th element is index 4).

Then it just adds 5 to `idx` every time. The magic is the modulo operator which makes it wrap around.

```
idx:      4   9   14   19   24   29
idx % 22: 4   9   14   19   2    7
element:  5   10  15   20   3    8
```

This will not guarantee you have 11 Bs for any array size - for that you'll have to only increment `numBs` if the previous element was G.

Output:

```
  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
  B  G  B  G  B  B  G  B  G  B  B  G  B  G  B  G  G  B  G  B  G  G
```

Answer (score 0):

The output you said you want is a bit incorrect. After the 3rd element, it is the **8th** element that must be set on B and not the 9th. This loop should be enough after you filled your list with "G"s:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 11; i++){
    circle.set(((i*5)%circle.size()) - 1, "B");
}
```

[Here](http://ideone.com/iMp5wH) is a demo of the code. If you can you'd might want to use an array of characters instead of a list of strings.